# Polling a database with long interval times, which is the best and most efficient way?

Tags: android, timer, alarmmanager, polling

How should I do this? I have been reading the posts but I don't see a clear answer to tell the truth.

I have been looking up the `AlarmManager` but it looked too complicated for something as simple as I want. I searched through the `Timer` class now, but I think you can't make it work when the application is closed. So which way should I choose? Which is the best way to check the server from time to time even if the app. is closed?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of server are you running that database on? Is it an ordinary web sever. I suggest having a look at GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Comment: Did you consider the combined usage of `AlarmManager` and `PendingIntent`? For eg see this [post](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html#scheduleservice_scheduling)

Comment: @DominicBartl I REALLY really would have loved to use GCM but neither have I time to understand GCM nor is it a short and easy service to build, you see I am in a bit of a deadline. I couldn't find an easy tutorial or an example for it too.

Comment: @Vino I have not actually, I don't have much (no) knowledge about this polling or pushing business. I will give it a try, to what you are suggesting

Comment: If your deadline isn't today you should be good to go to use GCM. It's not a hard service to build upon. You just have to start reading (and not just scan) the guide they provided. Google really described it step by step. http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html

Comment: @DominicBartl I wish I could ask you this in private somehow but I did the implementing the client part pretty well and easy but I somehow couldn't understand how to fire away messages from the server to the google cloud messaging server so I had to give up. I mean, is it doable from the database, I had to stop feeling idiotic.

Comment: @SuhrahjRothgar no you will need a server which is capable of sending a http request. Apache, Nginx, Node that sends a notification to the GCM servers.

Comment: @DominicBartl okay thanks a lot, my deadline 'is' actually for tomorrow but I will still be looking into this, I might change the direction of my project later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't get around `AlarmManager`. The only other client-side way would be to use a permanently running `Service`, but that is even more effort and less efficient.

Comment: what do you mean that I won't 'get around using it' ? How should I do it then?

Comment: Sorry, that was formulated a bit misleading. What I meant was you have to use `AlarmManager`.

Comment: ah... hahah all right, thanks a lot! will accept asap.

Answer (score 1):

As per the question i will favor the `AlarmManager` as do  not run the continuous services, for this purpose you can follow given steps

1 Set up an AlarmManager to fire in say 5 minutes, you can use yours timings 5 minutes is just arbitrary.

2 In the response of the alarm , you can start a service that will be able to  poll the data.

3 After polling it can set itself up with a new Alarm to fire again in another 5 minutes.

4 The service shuts down finally.

Comment: thanks a lot! but actually I was more curious about how to 'begin' doing it, so I am guessing that you are suggesting that I should use AlarmManager?

Comment: yes go with AlarmManager in my own opinion. it will be better